# GCC compiler cannot find hpp files

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to install the hep-mc library listed here: https://github.com/cschwan/hep-mc for use on compute using the instructions listed  in the documentation here: https://github.com/cschwan/hep-mc#installation . To compile one of the example files, I typed this into the terminal:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/hep-mc/include vegas_mpi_ex.cpp -o vegas_mpi
```

but I get these error messages:

```
mpi_vegas_ex.cpp:1:22: error: hep/mc.hpp: No such file or directory
mpi_vegas_ex.cpp:2:26: error: hep/mc-mpi.hpp: No such file or directory
mpi_vegas_ex.cpp:8:17: error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
```

in the beginning of my code, the declarations are like this:

```
#include "hep/mc.hpp"
#include "hep/mc-mpi.hpp"

#include <mpi.h>
```

The tutorial states that I should point the compiler to the location of the "include" folder that contains all the .hpp files, which I have done. Do you guys have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

It should also be noted that the compiler cannot find the mpi.h directory even though I have loaded the openmpi module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-L` sets paths where the linker searches for libraries to link. The option you're looking for is `-I`, which sets the paths where the compiler searches for `#include`d files.

Comment: An `-L` option might also be needed, if this isn't a header-only library

Comment: @MattMcNabb And/or `-l`, true.

Answer (score 2):

```
g++ -L/usr/local/hep-mc/include vegas_mpi_ex.cpp -o vegas_mpi
```

Oops!

```
g++ -I/usr/local/hep-mc/include vegas_mpi_ex.cpp -o vegas_mpi
```

`-L` specifies the path to library files; `-I` specifies the path to includes.

This is confusing because in terms of project management and distribution, we consider "the library" to include both binaries and header files, as well as documentation and all sorts of goodies. But at a technical level that is not what "library" means.